# RabbitMq Asynchronous call have to wait until subscriber return a response

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am using Rabbitmq for communicating between Publisher and subscriber . My publisher is pushing message to Queue and subscriber is doing some process and returning response back to publisher. My problem is Subscriber will take some time to execute process but the Publisher is not waiting until it get response from subscriber. Below is my code.
Publisher:

```
public void publishToDirectExchangeRPCStyle(String msg) {
        requestRoutingKey = Configuratins.requestRoutingKey;
        /*Integer integer = SECURE_RANDOM.nextInt();*/
        SampleRequestMessage sampleRequestMessage = new SampleRequestMessage(msg);
        System.out.println("Sending out message on direct directExchange:" + sampleRequestMessage);

        AsyncRabbitTemplate.RabbitConverterFuture<SampleResponseMessage> sampleResponseMessageRabbitConverterFuture = asyncRabbitTemplate
                        .convertSendAndReceive("spring-boot-rabbitmq-examples.async_rpc", "rpc_request", sampleRequestMessage);


        sampleResponseMessageRabbitConverterFuture.addCallback(
                        sampleResponseMessage ->{
                                        System.out.println("Response for request message:" + sampleRequestMessage + " is:" + sampleResponseMessage);
                                        try {
                                            mailClient.sendMail("Script Sucess",sampleResponseMessage.getMessage(), "");
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                        }
                        , failure ->{
                                        System.out.println(failure.getMessage()+"Failure section");

                                       /* try {
                                            mailClient.sendMail("Script Failure","1", "");
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }*/
                        }
        );



    }


}
```

Subscriber:

```
@EnableRabbit
public class Subscriber {

    @Autowired
    public Processor processor;
    @RabbitHandler
    @RabbitListener(containerFactory = "simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory", queues = "requestQueueRPC")
    public SampleResponseMessage subscribeToRequestQueue(@Payload SampleRequestMessage sampleRequestMessage, Message message) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Received message :" + message);
        int exitvalue=1;
        try {
            exitvalue=processor.executeProcess("FL");
            System.out.println("Exit value is:" +exitvalue);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        /*return new SampleResponseMessage(sampleRequestMessage.getMessage());*/
        return new SampleResponseMessage(new Integer(exitvalue).toString());
    }
}
```

in publisher **sampleResponseMessageRabbitConverterFuture.addCallback(
                        sampleResponseMessage ->{** is not waiting until it receives response back. Is there any way we can set it to wait until it get response back?